# Ratings within Demographic using IMDBPy

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

Is any way to get the movie ratings distribution by demographics using imdbpy? For example, I can get this data

- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/ratings

with the following code

```
import imdb
i = imdb.IMDb(accessSystem='http')
movie = i.get_movie('0780504')
i.update(movie, 'vote details')
movie['demographics']
```

but can I get these distributions?

- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/ratings?demo=aged_under_18
- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/ratings?demo=males_aged_under_18
- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/ratings?demo=females_aged_under_18

etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to access those information.

Anyway, it would be easy to add a way to access them, since the parser is the same and it's just a matter of adding some methods to the `imdb.parser.http.IMDbHTTPAccessSystem` class.

I suggest to open an issue requesting the feature.